# Can I play Minecraft in my phone's browser?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I love playing Minecraft and I started playing it on my phone four or three years ago. However, I stopped, and now it's 2022 I redownloaded the game. There are so many updates, and I certainly am very outdated in Minecraft.

There is this one thing, too. Minecraft is running very, very slow on my phone. At first I get the red and white 'Mojang' logo (which wasn't red before), then a black screen which lasts for almost 5 minutes. Then I see the Minecraft logo, and it loads for a long time. Then I create a world and it takes approximately 6 or 7 minutes to load.
Is it because my phone is old and can't take the new Minecraft? I don't really know, but it doesn't really matter, as I don't know how to fix it. My only solution is to play Minecraft in my browser. I have heard of 'Minecraft Classic', but when I went there, it just told me I need a keyboard for that. Which means I gotta go to my computer.

But **is there any way I can play Minecraft on my browser on the phone?**

Comment: Let's start with telling us your specific phone. Surely it wouldn't hurt you.

Comment: Skye-AT I'm not sure but I think my phone is Samsung note 4.

Comment: That phone is 8 years old, which is ancient when it comes to cellphones. The browser-based version of Minecraft Classic ran as a Java applet. AFAIK modern web browsers don't support those anymore.

Comment: *"Is it because my phone is old and can't take the new Minecraft? I don't really know, but it doesn't really matter, as I don't know how to fix it."* It seems you already do know how to fix it. If your phone is old and can't handle the current version of Minecraft, the only way to "fix" it is get a new phone that is capable of running it.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. There's no official version of Minecraft on browser that would save your progress, and Minecraft Classic is exclusive to keyboard; even if you could get it running on your phone, you'd need an external keyboard and mouse connected (both via bluetooth) to be able to play at all - and it wouldn't save. It's cheaper to just buy a new phone.

Comment: For reference, a Samsung A13 is under $200 and probably could handle mobile minecraft.

Comment: Or find an older version of the app somehow.

Comment: Just get a new phone